# What is the point of multinomial vs argmax evaluation of accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

What is the purpose of evaluating prediction accuracy using `multinomial` instead of the straight up `argmax`?

```py
probs_Y = torch.softmax(model(test_batch, feature_1, feature_2), 1)

sampled_Y = torch.multinomial(probs_Y, 1)
argmax_Y = torch.max(probs_Y, 1)[1].view(-1, 1)

print('Accuracy of sampled predictions on the test set: {:.4f}%'.format(
    (test_Y == sampled_Y.float()).sum().item() / len(test_Y) * 100))
print('Accuracy of argmax predictions on the test set: {:4f}%'.format(
    (test_Y == argmax_Y.float()).sum().item() / len(test_Y) * 100))
```

Result:

```
Accuracy of sampled predictions on the test set: 88.8889%

Accuracy of argmax predictions on the test set: 97.777778%
```

Reading the pytorch docs it looks like [multinomial](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#multinomial) is sampling according to some distribution - just not sure how that is relevant in assessing accuracy.

I've noticed that the multinomial is non-deterministic - meaning that it is outputting a different accuracy, presumably by including different samples, each time it runs.

Comment: This concept is similar to the `micro` vs `macro` methodologies of multi-class ROC curves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, with `multinomial` - we're sampling the classes with the multinomial distribution.

From the Wikipedia example,

> Suppose that in a three-way election for a large country, candidate A
>   received 20% of the votes, candidate B received 30% of the votes, and
>   candidate C received 50% of the votes. If six voters are selected
>   randomly, what is the probability that there will be exactly one
>   supporter for candidate A, two supporters for candidate B and three
>   supporters for candidate C in the sample?
>
> Note: Since we’re assuming that the voting population is large, it is
>   reasonable and permissible to think of the probabilities as unchanging
>   once a voter is selected for the sample. Technically speaking this is
>   sampling without replacement, so the correct distribution is the
>   multivariate hypergeometric distribution, but the distributions
>   converge as the population grows large.

If we look closely, we're doing the same, **sampling without replacement**.

`torch.multinomial(input, num_samples, replacement=False, *, generator=None, out=None)`

ref: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=torch%20multinomial#torch.multinomial

A multinomial experiment is a statistical experiment and it consists of n repeated trials. Each trial has a discrete number of possible outcomes. On any given trial, the probability that a particular outcome will occur is constant (that was the initial assumption).

[image]

So, the voting count can be simulated with the probabilities. **Classification from soft outputs is a similar voting process.**

If we repeat the experiment enough times, we'll reach as close as the actual probability.

For example, let's start with an initial `probs = [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5]`.

We can repeat the experiment `n` times and count how many times an index was selected by `torch.multinomial`.

```
import torch

cnt = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for _ in range(5000):
  sampled_Y = torch.multinomial(torch.tensor([0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5]), 1)
  cnt[sampled_Y[0]] += 1

print(cnt)
```

After 50 iterations: `[6, 3, 14, 27]`

After 5000 iterations: `[480, 486, 1525, 2509]`

After 50000 iterations: `[4988, 4967, 15062, 24983]`

But, this is avoided in model evaluation since it's not deterministic and requires a random generator to simulate the experiment. This is particularly useful for monte-carlo simulations, prior-posterior calculation. I have seen a graph classification example, where such evaluation was used. But I think it's not common and (even useful) in most classification tasks in machine learning.

Comment: Haha this code probably came from that same graph classification tutorial.